# Can I conclude that $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^2}{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})^2}$ is infinite or it doesn't exists?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity, wolfram-alpha

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^2}{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})^2}$$

My intuition is that the denominator goes to 0 faster and everything is non-negative, so the limit is positive infinity.

I cant think of elementary proof, l'Hopital doesn't help here, and I'm not sure if and how to use taylor.

WolframAlpha [says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28x-%3E0%2B%29%28%28x%5E2%29%2F%28e%5E-%281%2Fx%5E2%29%2Acos%281%2Fx%5E2%29%5E2%29%29) it's complex infinity, but I can't understand why it doesn't just real positive infinity.

I've [tried](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%28%28x%5E2%29%2F%28e%5E-%281%2Fx%5E2%29%2Acos%281%2Fx%5E2%29%5E2%29%29%2C%20x%20-%3E%200%2C%20Assumptions%20-%3E%20Element%5Bx%2C%20Reals%5D%2C%20%20Direction%20-%3E%20-1%5D) to use wolfram language to use the assumption that x is real, but couldn't get any result.

Comment: someone vote to close as off-topic, I can't understand why... I'm mentioning WA just as an aside, I ask about a limit and describe what have I tried. can't see, why this might be considered off-topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^2}{\exp\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)}$$is indeed $+\infty$. Since $\dfrac1{\cos^2\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)}\geqslant1$ for each $x$ (when it is defined), you are right: the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: thanks! so if I want to be as rigorous as possible, the limit doesn't exists just because of the points where it's undefined? or can I just ignore them?

Comment: That depends upon the definition of limit that you are using. **If** it requires that the function is defined in som interval $(0,\varepsilon)$, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: ok, will check. thanks!

Comment: @user376343 yes it's

Answer (score 4):

The function is not finite valued. If you allow the value $\infty$ then the limit is $\infty$. Use L'Hôpital's Rule twice to show that $\frac {e^{y}} {y^{2}} \to \infty$ as $y \to \infty$. Replace $y$ by $\frac 1 {x^{2}}$ and use the fact that $|\cos (t)| \leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks! value of $\infty$? I'm not using "one point compactification" or "extended real line" if that was your meaning, division by the number 0 is not allowed. I do use a definition which allow infinite limits or limits at infinity. Using this change of variable, I still get 0 in the denominator infinitely many times as y goes to $\infty$...

Comment: @User In that case you have to say that function is not defined in $(0,a)$ for any $a>0$ so the limit is not defined.